# Proving that a map is weak* continuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact space, $C(X)$ the space of continuous functions on $X$, and $\mathscr{M} = C(X)^*$, the dual of $C(X)$ which we identify with the space of all complex Baire measures. Let $$\mathscr{M}_+(X) = \{ \ell \in \mathscr{M}(X)| \text{ $\ell$ is a positive continuous linear functional}\} \\ \mathscr{M}_{+,1}(X) = \{\ell \in \mathscr{M}_+ ~\big\vert~ \|\ell\| = 1\}.$$

For any $\mu \in \mathscr{M}_{+,1}$ and $g \in X$, let $T_g\mu$ be defined by $T_g \mu(f) = \mu(f_g)$ where $f_g(h) = f(h-g)$.

I would like to show that $T_g$ is continuous in the weak* topology. Let $\{\mu_n\}$ be any sequence of measures in $\mathscr{M}_{+,1}$ such that $\mu_n \rightarrow \mu$ in the weak* topology, which means
$$\mu_n(f) \rightarrow \mu(f), \quad \forall f \in C(X).$$
Then for any $f$,
$$T_g \mu_n(f) = \mu_n(f_g) \rightarrow \mu(f_g) = T_g \mu(f)$$
so $T_g$ preserves convergence of sequences. However, I do not have any reason to believe that the weak* topology is first countable so I am not sure if this is sufficient or correct.

What is the standard approach to showing that a map between two dual spaces is weak* continuous? I do not see how to prove this straight from the definition of continuity (preimage of open sets being open).

Comment: Is it not that every $\ell\in \mathcal M$ is a continuous linear functional on $C(X)$? Am I missing something about $\mathcal M_+$?

Comment: All you need to do is use nets or filters instead of sequences and the proof you gave carries through and is valid for any topology.  It doesn't have to be first countable.

Comment: @NewB That was a typo, thanks for catching that. I have edited my post.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The definition $f_g(h)=f((h-g)$ does not make sense for general compact spaces $X$. You need a group sturcture on $X$ to define this translation.

Comment: Poor choice of notations. If you have used $f$ for functions in $C(X)$ then one should avoid using $g,h$ for elements in $X$.

Comment: @Jochen The space is indeed assumed to also be an abelian group, my apologies I forgot to include that.